# Why does dynamic work in the first case but not in the second?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamic

This passes

```
        var badRequestObjectResult = new BadRequestObjectResult(new { ErrorMessage = "Hi" });
        dynamic response = badRequestObjectResult.Value;
        Assert.Equal("Hi", response.ErrorMessage);
```

While this fails

```
        dynamic response2 = ((BadRequestObjectResult)result).Value;//result is an IActionResult
        Assert.Equal("Hi", response2.ErrorMessage);
```

> "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ErrorMessage'"

Comment: Where is "result" coming from in the second example?

Comment: A method that in the signature returns IActionResult and in the body returns a BadRequestObjectResult constructing that object as in the code that passes: new BadRequestObjectResult(new { ErrorMessage = "Hi" });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to extend your answer to include a complete and reproducible example. What you describe works as expected without an error so there must be something in-between that is causing an issue such as custom cloning or serialization that is altering the recognized type behind the ObjectResult's Value.

```
[Test]
public void TestDynamic()
{
    var response1 = new BadRequestObjectResult(new { Message = "Hi." });
    var response2 = buildResponse();

    dynamic value1 = response1.Value;
    dynamic value2 = ((BadRequestObjectResult)response2).Value;

    string message1 = value1.Message;
    string message2 = value2.Message;

    Assert.AreEqual(message1, message2);
}

private IActionResult buildResponse()
{
    return new BadRequestObjectResult(new { Message = "Hi." });
}
```

About the only way I could reproduce the error was if buildResponse returned:

```
return new BadRequestObjectResult(new object());
```

Returning anything like an anonymous type or another class that lacked a Message property resulted in a message that reflected the underlying type.

Comment: Thanks, will review it then more in depth. Does it matter that the method returning the IActionResult is an Azure Function?

Comment: Possibly, it really depends on the code that populates that object result. For instance if I have a C# code that populates it with an anonymous type and returns it, the call resolves it as an anonymous type through the Object parameter. If instead it serializes and deserializes it via JSON the check would see it as a JSON object but still resolve that Message property.  The error would indicate that the sender or possibly communication is resulting in the Value being sent as an Object instance rather than a type (Containing Message) accessed via Object.